# Dojo Build Tool

Tags: dojo-build

error(311) Missing dependency. module: app/ui/module/Widget1; dependency: appui/module/Widget2

The Dojo build tool does not take into consideration the configuration provided in the "paths" property of the Profile object

I have coded "paths" property as follows

paths : {
  appui : "app/ui"
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe "paths" is a valid property of the profile object.

The profile object often looks something like:

```
var profile = {
  basePath:"/home/user/dev/",
  releaseDir:"./release",
  packages:[{
    name:"dojo",
    location:"./lib/dojo"
  },{
    name:"dijit",
    location:"./lib/dijit"
  },{
    name:"myapp",
    location:"./myapp"
  }]
}
```

More info here: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/buildSystem.html#specifying-resources